# Mixing WebAPI and MVC AttributeRouting with Route Prefix?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm pretty new to setting up routes and routing in MVC. At my last job we used attribute routing for our WebAPI stuff, so I'm pretty familiar with that (`RoutePrefix`, `Route`, and `HttpGet`/`HttpPost` attributes, etc). And I can get my current project to work just fine with attributes.

So now what I want to do is "prefix" all of the webApi routes with "api". So instead of going to mysite/test/hello, I want to go to mysite/**api**/test/hello.

This is what I have, using only attribute routing, and it works just fine:

```
[RoutePrefix("Test")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{ ....

  [HttpPost]
  [Route("{message}")]
  public HttpResponse EchoBack(string message)
  {
      // return message ... in this case, "hello"
  }
}
```

Now, I know I can change the `RoutePrefix` to "api/Test" (which works 100%), but I don't want to change all my controllers, I would rather be able to perform this by changing the values passed in to `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute` in WebApiConfig.

Is this possible?

Comment: What you are describing is convention-based routing, which does not mix well with attribute routing on the same controller.  The controller either conforms to convention-based routing or attribute routing. not both. You can have different controllers either all attribute or all convention-based. Attribute routing allows for more flexibility though IMO. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi. So what you're saying is, if I want to change my attribute-based controllers to prefix them with "api", I should do it in the RoutePrefix attribute in each controller, and ignore the conventions/maps? (I'll read that MSDN article tonight, thanks for finding that!!)

Comment: No. not on every controller. I found an even better article that should be exactly what you are looking for http://www.strathweb.com/2015/10/global-route-prefixes-with-attribute-routing-in-asp-net-web-api/

Answer (score 1):

What you describe can be done in attribute routing by using what is referred to as a global route prefix.

Referencing this article [Global route prefixes with attribute routing in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.strathweb.com/2015/10/global-route-prefixes-with-attribute-routing-in-asp-net-web-api/)

Create a `DirectRouteProvider`

```
public class CentralizedPrefixProvider : DefaultDirectRouteProvider {
    private readonly string _centralizedPrefix;

    public CentralizedPrefixProvider(string centralizedPrefix) {
        _centralizedPrefix = centralizedPrefix;
    }

    protected override string GetRoutePrefix(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor) {
        var existingPrefix = base.GetRoutePrefix(controllerDescriptor);
        if (existingPrefix == null) return _centralizedPrefix;

        return string.Format("{0}/{1}", _centralizedPrefix, existingPrefix);
    }
}
```

To quote article.

> The `CentralizedPrefixProvider` shown above, takes a prefix that is
>   globally prepended to every route. If a particular controller has it’s
>   own route prefix (obtained via the `base.GetRoutePrefix` method
>   invocation), then the centralized prefix is simply prepended to that
>   one too.

Configure it in the WebAPiConfig like this

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(new CentralizedPrefixProvider("api"));
```

So now for example if you have a controller like this

```
[RoutePrefix("Test")]
public class TestController : ApiController {
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("{message}")]
    public IHttpActionResult EchoBack(string message) { ... }
}
```

The above action will be accessed via

```
<<host>>/api/Test/{message}
```

where `api` will be prepended to the controller actions route.